# XSLT namespace and resolving hard-coded prefix

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

For a Google Merchant Center integration I need to provide XML, where *some* of the elements have a namespace prefix, for example:

```
   <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>,
```

whilst other do not require the namespace, for example:

```
   <title>My Product</title>
```

However, I cannot come up with an XSLT that will allow me:

1) specify the corresponding namespace (xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")
AND
2) prefix attributes

, WITHOUT a "g" namespace being added in somewhere.

---

exclude-result-prefixes="g" does not work for my use case, I believe. To re-iterate, I need to prefix some XML elements with the "g". If I did not need to do this, e.g.

```
<availability>in stock<availability>
```

, then exclude-result-prefixes works fine. However, when I add the prefix to my element, the namespace gets added in when the XSLT runs. I have an example of this scenario below.

Thanks.

---

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:element name="type">
        <xsl:for-each select="categories/product">
            <xsl:element name="product">
                <g:availability>
                    <xsl:text>preorder</xsl:text>
                </g:availability>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

---

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
<product>
<id>1</id> 
<preorder>true</preorder>
<releaseDate>true</releaseDate>
<quantity>1</quantity>
</product>
<product>
<id>2</id> 
<preorder>false</preorder>
<quantity>0</quantity>
</product>
<product>
<id>3</id> 
<preorder></preorder>
<quantity>10</quantity>
</product>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<type>
<product>
<g:availability xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">preorder</g:availability>
</product>
<product>
<g:availability xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">preorder</g:availability>
</product>
<product>
<g:availability xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">preorder</g:availability>
</product>
</type>
```

(incomplete) Google Merchant, expected XML example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Example - Online Store</title>
<item>
<title>LG Flatron M2262D 22" Full HD LCD TV</title>
<g:id>TV_123456</g:id>
<g:condition>used</g:condition>
</item>     
</channel>
</rss>
```

---

Using version 1 of XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the namespace declaration *somewhere* as the XML is not namespace-well-formed without it, but you can make it appear just once on the root element rather than repeatedly on every `<g:availability>` by declaring the namespace in the stylesheet and using a literal root element in the template rather than an `<xsl:element>`.  For example, to generate something similar to the Google example you supplied in the question, you could say:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rss version="2.0">
            <channel>
                <title>Example - Online Store</title>
                <xsl:for-each select="categories/product">
                    <item>
                        <g:id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></g:id>
                        <g:availability>preorder</g:availability>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
             </channel>
        </rss>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should produce

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Example - Online Store</title>
    <item>
      <g:id>1</g:id>
      <g:availability>preorder</g:availability>
    </item>
    <item>
      <g:id>2</g:id>
      <g:availability>preorder</g:availability>
    </item>
    <item>
      <g:id>3</g:id>
      <g:availability>preorder</g:availability>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

The reason this works is because literal result elements carry the namespace bindings that are in scope at their place in the stylesheet over into the result tree.

Comment: Thanks Ian. "You need the namespace declaration somewhere" - do you mean in addition to the declaration in the header? So the problem with this solution is that Google Merchant treats this namesapce as a URL - in so far as it will try and verify it (the verification involves comparing URLs to the single URL defined for the site). regarding my first point, Ill update the original quetsion with a complete XML example that Google Expect, thanks.

Comment: @Damo my point is that there must be an `xmlns:g` in the output document, either on the `<g:availability>` element itself, or on one of its parent elements.  The example you give is fine because the namespace is declared on the root `<rss>` element.

Comment: so its fine for the xmlns:g entry to solely be declared on the root rss element(?) That is what my "production" XSLT is doing - via something roughly like this:                                          
    <xsl:text><rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">></xsl:text> . So with this is place, and a well-formed XML now being guaranteed, how can I prevent the namespace being added to other elements. (I see how using the literal element name "shifts" the namespace up to its parent - but I dont even want the parent to have the namespace - just the rss element). Thanks

Comment: @Damo I've edited my example to be more in line with the Google XML you supplied, does that make any more sense now?  The root element generated by the `<xsl:template match="/">` is `<rss>`, and that gets the `xmlns:g`.

Comment: @Damo glad to help.  When you get an answer that solves your problem, it's good manners to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer.  If you build a track record of accepting good answers people will be more willing to help you with your future questions.